# Update the specific field and not the whole document in MongoDB with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, crud

I'm using MongoDB 3.2 and MongoDB Java Driver 3.2. In order to update the document I use the following code:

```java
unfetchedEpisodes.stream()
    .forEach(ep -> {
        BasicDBObject updatedFields = new BasicDBObject();
        updatedFields.append("fetchStatus", "IN_PROCESS");

        updateColFields(updatedFields, dbCollection, new ObjectId(ep.get("_id").toString()));
    });

public void updateColFields(BasicDBObject updatedFields, MongoCollection<Document> dbCollection, ObjectId docID) {

    BasicDBObject setQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    setQuery.append("$set", updatedFields);

    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject("_id", docID);

    dbCollection.updateOne(searchQuery, setQuery);
}
```

This code works but I'm not sure that this code updates ***only the specific field*** (e.g. `fetchStatus`) of the document and not overwrites the whole document.

Does this code update *only the specific field* of the document or simply overwrites *the whole document*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just updates the specified field. The field will be created if it doesn't exist. Other fields remain untouched. According to [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/):

> The $set operator replaces the value of a field with the specified value.

and

> If the field does not exist, $set will add a new field with the specified value, provided that the new field does not violate a type constraint. If you specify a dotted path for a non-existent field, $set will create the embedded documents as needed to fulfill the dotted path to the field.